# mvn unsupported packaging type: pom

Tags: maven

A college of me had several times the following problem with maven:

```
mvn unsupported packaging type: pom
```

Pom's are the base for maven, so I find this very strange. It can be solved by removing downloaded repositories, just to get back again.
For example: last Thursday she removed the repositories and let maven download them again, but this morning she got the message back. By removing the downloaded repositories and letting maven download them again we got it working again, but that is not really solution.

It looks quit unique because I did not find anything about it on the internet. Anyone an idea what the problem could be?
She is working with Java 1.8.0_212 and maven 3.6.0.